# Laravel 404 exception caught by handler gives 200 on testing the path with CURL or browser

Tags: laravel, http-status-code-404

Some of the valid Urls are treated as 404 exception, but actually they can be successfully browsed and curled with 200.

It only happens when  `new \Jenssegers\Agent\Agent()->isRobot()` is `true`. **How can I make the Urls valid (200) for those robots? when Urls are actually valid**

In `app/Exceptions/Handler.php` I have

```
public function render($request, Throwable $exception)
{
    $code = null;
    if(method_exists($exception, 'getStatusCode'))
    {
        $code = $exception->getStatusCode();
    }
    $path = $request->path();
    if($code === 404) {
        Logger::note_request_error($request, $code, $path);
    }
    return parent::render($request, $exception);
}
```

In `app/Logger.php` I have

```
static function note_request_error($request, $status_code, $path){
    $site_url = env('app.site_url');
    $staus = Http::timeout(4)->get($site_url.$path)->status();
    if($staus == 200){
         $agent = new \Jenssegers\Agent\Agent();
         if($agent->isRobot()){
             $known_robot = $agent->robot();
             //AhrefsBot, GoogleBot
         }
         return 'Ops, I came here with 404, so how can I know the reason for this happening, why 200 now?'
    }
    else{
        // note_this_not_reached_url($path);
    }
}
```

Comment: Strange. Can you please issue some cache clear command such as `artisan optimize:clear` then try again.

Comment: I did, but no luck